# Combinatorics: Select at least one full professor

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question in the combinatorics section of my book

> The Math department of a small college has three full professors, seven associate professors, and four assistant professors. In how many ways can a four member committee be formed under the restriction that at least one full professor is selected.

The way I solved this problem was to see it as at least 1 full professor or at least 2 full professors or at least 3 full professors

$3\choose 1$ $11\choose 3$ $+$ $3\choose 2$ $11\choose 2$ $+$ $3\choose 3$ $11\choose 1$

But the answer in the book is $14\choose 4$ $-$ $11\choose 4$. Can someone tell me why my way of doing it is wrong and why book's answer is right?

Comment: Note that both expressions equal $671$ so your approach is fine.

Comment: In many areas of mathematics, and in combinatorics especially, there are multiple equally valid and sometimes wildly different approaches to a problem which may have answers appear in different forms while being equal despite their different appearances.  Knowing that the answers should be the same yet finding that they look different is a common and effective form of proof for why those expressions must in fact be equal.  In your case, you discovered that by moving the $\binom{11}{4}$ to the other side and generalizing that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^a\binom{a}{k}\binom{n-a}{r-k}=\binom{n}{r}$.

Comment: As an aside, your phrasing of your solution is off.  "*The way I solved this... see it as* **at least 1** *full professor or* **at least 2**..."  This should be rephrased as "... *see it as* **exactly 1** *full professor or* **exactly 2**..."  The phrase 'at least' has a distinctly different meaning than 'exactly' and should not be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the number of associate professors and assistant professors $(7 + 4) = 11$ to compute the number of professors who are not full-professors.

There are:

- $3$ full professors
- $11$ professors who are not full-professors.
- $14$ total professors
  $$
  \begin{array}
  \text{\phantom{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}} \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$

There are a few other quantities of interest:

- $\mathrm{ANSWER}$: The number of ways that a four member committee be formed under the restriction that $\underline{\textbf{at least one}}$ full professor is selected.
- $\mathrm{TOTAL}$: The number of ways that a four member committee be formed under no special restrictions
- $\mathrm{UNDESIRABLE}$:The number of ways that a four member committee be formed under the restriction that $\underline{\textbf{no}}$ full professors are on committee at all.
  $$
  \begin{array}
  \text{\phantom{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}} \\
  \hline
  \end{array}
  $$

The author of your textbook was thinking that:

$\mathrm{ANSWER} = \mathrm{TOTAL} - \mathrm{UNDESIRABLE}$

Note that:

$\mathrm{TOTAL} =  \binom{14}{4}$

$\mathrm{UNDESIRABLE} =  \binom{11}{4}$

$\mathrm{UNDESIRABLE}$ is $\binom{11}{4}$ because you are choosing 4 people from the pool of 11 non-full professors.

Comment: Previously you had answer = total = undesirable, but I'm pretty sure you meant total - undesirable, so I edited slightly.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, your answer is fine. The book probably reasoned via "inclusion exclusion," i.e. there are $\binom{14}{4}$ total committees that can be created, and of those $\binom{11}{4}$ contain no full professors, thus the desired answer is the difference between the two.